# C macro for defining symbols

Tags: c, macros

I'm working with a microcontroller with ANSI C (gcc; not C++) and have a lot of hardware pins to define.  I'm looking for a way to make the pin definitions more readable.

I think I'd like a macro that would let me define each pin in a single line, like this:

```
PIN(LED_RED, E, 2);  
PIN(LED_YELLOW, B, 3);  
PIN(LED_GREEN, A, 4);
```

(this is just a simple example - I've dozens of pins to define).
Right now I have ugly looking code like this:

```
#define LED_RED           (LATEbits.LATE2)  
#define LED_RED_TRIS      (TRISEbits.TRISE2)  

#define LED_YELLOW        (LATBbits.LATB3)   
#define LED_YELLOW_TRIS   (TRISBbits.TRISB3)    

#define LED_GREEN         (LATAbits.LATA4)    
#define LED_GREEN_TRIS    (TRISAbits.TRISA4)
```

Each pin has 2 symbols; one to read/write the pin, and another to set the I/O direction (the _TRIS definitions).  The latch and TRIS definitions come from a header library supplied by the MCU vendor; it's not really practical to avoid using them.

I'm fairly sure it is possible to write a macro in C that will define both symbols, but I'm not very good with the # and ## stuff.  Here is my half-baked attempt (doesn't work):

```
#define _PIN( id,port,pos) #define ##id (LAT ##port ##bits.LAT ##port ##pos )  
#define _TRIS(id,port,pos) #define ##id _TRIS (TRIS ##port ##bits .TRIS ##port ##pos )  
#define PIN(  id,port,pos) _PIN(id,port,pos)  _TRIS(id,port,pos)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Or, is there another way to simplify my pin definitions?  I'd like to get it down to one line/pin, and to get rid of the duplication of port id (A,B,C, etc.) and bit number (2,3,4, etc.) that I have now; putting them in twice is just asking for trouble.

Cheers,

--Dave

Comment: Can you clarify what all the arguments to your macro would do?  Right now I don't understand what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: One macro cannot define other macros. But perhaps your problem could be simplified at a different level?

Comment: Sure.  The first argument (ex: "LED_RED") is used to define both symbols; one called "LED_RED" and the other called "LED_RED_TRIS" (by appending "_TRIS").  The 2nd and 3rd arguments get substituted into the macro replacement strings to form "LATEbits.LATE2" (where the E and 2 come from the arguments).

Comment: Ugly code? It's beautiful, it follow all standards, throw a comment or two and it would be perfect. If you have to make 500 billion lines like this, just make a little program to print em into a .h file for you :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't define macros in macros, but you can do some other tricks.

This is in the "fairly ugly macro" territory.

```
#define MY_CAT(x, y) x ## y
#define MY_CAT2(x, y) MY_CAT(x, y)
#define LED(x) (MY_CAT2(MY_CAT2(LAT, PORT_ ## x), bits) \
                .MY_CAT2(LAT, MY_CAT2(PORT_ ## x, POS_ ## x)))

#define PORT_RED E
#define POS_RED 2
#define PORT_YELLOW B
#define POS_YELLOW 3
#define PORT_GREEN A
#define POS_GREEN 4

LED(RED)
LED(YELLOW)
LED(GREEN)
```

The expansion (check with `gcc -E`) is:

```
(LATEbits .LATE2)
(LATBbits .LATB3)
(LATAbits .LATA4)
```

Just because macros are your hammer doesn't mean this is a nail.  Try generating the source code with Python or something, much nicer.

```
LEDS = [
    ('RED', 'E2'),
    ('YELLOW', 'B3'),
    ('GREEN', 'A4'),
]
for name, pos in LEDS:
    print '#define LED_%s (LAT%sbits.LAT%s)' % (name, pos[0], pos)
    print '#define LED_%s_TRIS (TRIS%sbits.TRIS%s)' % (name, pos[0], pos)
```

The output is:

```
#define LED_RED (LATEbits.LATE2)
#define LED_RED_TRIS (TRISEbits.TRISE2)
#define LED_YELLOW (LATBbits.LATB3)
#define LED_YELLOW_TRIS (TRISBbits.TRISB3)
#define LED_GREEN (LATAbits.LATA4)
#define LED_GREEN_TRIS (TRISAbits.TRISA4)
```

Then you just go ahead and check both the script and its output into your revision control system.

**Addendum:** I'm not going to explain how the macro trick works because I don't want to learn the trick well enough to explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately that solution just moves the complexity from the "LED(RED)" line up to the #defines. (and most of the pins aren't LEDs - they're switches, inputs and outputs, etc.)  If anything, I think this result is less readable than what I started with.  But the example of how to use ## is valuable - thanks for that.  I think I'm going to look at an external pre-processor for this.